# Change textview to println output

Tags: kotlin

I have a response from an api but I can't seem to print it to a textview
I tried to do what people said on the forum but nothing works

I tried using

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)
textView.setText(response)
```

but that dosent work
here is some code

```
val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
println(request)
println(response)
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)
textView.setText(response)
```

I just want to know how i could print the response from the api.

Comment: How do you get the response? What is the type of the response?

Comment: The response is here ```Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK``` I used print ln for that. But i want to have that print to a textview

Comment: Then you probably just want to call `textView.setText(response.toString())` (println does that for you automatically)

Comment: when doing that the application crashed Why is that? this is the error
```android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update UI directly in non-main thread.

try to use handler or runOnUiThread().

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // update TextView here
                    textView.setText(response)
                }
            });
```

Comment: I did this ```        val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
        textView.setOnClickListener {
             textView.setText(response.toString()) ```